# Is it possible to import a targets file if the msbuild project contains certain items?

Tags: msbuild

Given:

1. Hundreds of *.csproj across multiple solutions
2. Some *.csproj files also contain `TypescriptCompile` elements.
3. The *.csproj files from (2) are NOT concentrated under a dedicated subdirectory.

Required: import a certain targets file into those projects that contain `TypescriptCompile` elements.

The trivial solution is to include the `Import` statement in each and every project containing the `TypescriptCompile` elements.

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same without explicitly importing the aforementioned targets file, i.e. utilize the Directory.Build.props/Directory.Build.targets files. However, I also know that `Import` conditions cannot reference items.

One way would be to do something like this:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectText>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(MSBuildProjectFullPath)))</ProjectText>
    <IsTypescriptCompile>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('$(ProjectText)', '<TypescriptCompile Include', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))</IsTypescriptCompile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)TypescriptCompile.targets" Condition="'$(IsTypescriptCompile)' == true" />
</Project>
```

(the regex can be more sophisticated)

But it is not very robust. Is there a better way?

**EDIT 1**

The naive approach of checking `'@(TypescriptCompile)' != ''` does not work.

We can test it with these 2 simple files:

```
C:\work\TestImport> cat .\1.targets
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypescriptCompile Include="abc" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="1.xml" Condition="'@(TypescriptCompile)' != ''" />
</Project>
C:\work\TestImport> cat .\1.xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="kuku" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="*** $(MSBuildProjectName)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
</Project>
C:\work\TestImport> MSBuild.exe /t:Build .\1.targets /v:q
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\work\TestImport\1.targets(6,27): error MSB4099: A reference to an item list at position 2 is not allowed in this condition "'@(TypescriptCompile)' != ''".
C:\work\TestImport>
```

Googling reveals that using items in an import condition is not supported. So the brute force does not work, but maybe there is some other solution, less ugly than my current workaround.

Comment: Can't you just use `'@(TypescriptCompile)' != ''` as condition? Or does that not work due to evaluation order perhaps?

Comment: Not allowed - see my EDIT 1.

Comment: Right, that falls under evaluation/execution order I guess; even with a workaround like setting a property to the value of @(TypescriptCompile) you couldn't use that property as conditions; well, you could, but at the time msbuild evaluates the Import it will just see the condition as the literal @(TypescriptCompile)' != '' string. Not super clear but this is because of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022 and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/comparing-properties-and-items?view=vs-2022#property-and-item-evaluation-order

Comment: So this is it? My workaround is lame, but it is the best?

Comment: I didn't look very hard perhaps, but yes, I do not immediately see another way.